# overview_path of the Directions Service api returns encoded lat lang

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to get the longitude and latitude of the route. When I check the directions response object I see that overview_path returns an array of longitude and latitude but it is I think encoded.

[image: [enter image description here]()]

This is what it looks like. Can someone please explain in which format is it and how can I get the longitude and latitude in numbers format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Routes).  [`overview_path`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsRoute.overview_path) is an array of `google.maps.LatLng` objects, each of them has a [`.lat()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng.lat) and a [`.lng()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng.lng) method that returns the associated latitude and longitude.

```
  var overview_path=response.routes[0].overview_path;
  for (var i=0; i<overview_path.length;i++) {
    console.log("latitude="+overview_path[i].lat()+", longitude="+overview_path[i].lng())
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle (logs each latitude/longitude from the overview_path)](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wv3pjkhg/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {
      lat: 41.85,
      lng: -87.65
    },
  });

  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  calculateAndDisplayRoute("New York, NY", "Newark,NJ", directionsService, directionsRenderer);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(start, end, directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
  directionsService
    .route({
      origin: {
        query: start,
      },
      destination: {
        query: end,
      },
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
      var overview_path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
      for (var i = 0; i < overview_path.length; i++) {
        console.log("latitude=" + overview_path[i].lat() + ", longitude=" + overview_path[i].lng())
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status));
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", "sans-serif";
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Directions Service</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- 
     The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
     document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
     and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises
     with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader.
    -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```